# "Call to a member function setState() on bool" with responsivizer component after upgrading from joomla 3.9 to 3.10

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.10

After updating my Joomla site from version 3.9 to 3.10, everything is working except the responsivizer component where I am getting this error in the backend:

> Call to a member function setState() on bool

I enabled debug mode and found that error is happening in this line of setstate:

```
F:\www\4nov\administrator\components\com_responsivizer\controllers\cpanel.php:27
```

My PHP version is 7.4 before and after upgrading.

I checked on PHP 7.4 in Joomla 3.9.x with a backup and there was no error.

It seems that the issue is exclusive to Joomla 3.10.

```
function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false) {
    $defaultModel = $this->getModel();
    $defaultModel->setState('option', $this->option);
    
    // Dependency injection setter on view/model for ResponsivizerRegistry instance
    $view = $this->getView();
    $registry = new ResponsivizerRegistry();
    $view->set('registry', $registry);
    $HTTPClient = new ResponsivizerHttp();
    $view->set('httpclient', $HTTPClient);
    
    // No operations
    parent::display ($cachable); 
}
```

Comment: What version of Responsivizer do you have installed?

Comment: Well thats an old version only as not having funds to buy in renewal. It was last bought in 3 yrs back and that same version went will on to php 7,4 and joomla 3.9, but after update to j3.10 - facing this. i presume by correcting this errror will be able to get same working

Comment: $this->getModel() returns false. You might try to use $this->getModel("model_name") but I don't have this extension so I don't know what model_name to assume and what was set to be default.